# How to update button width without css ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

I trying to update the width size of  to 50% without using css, but there is error when I use the way below

```
<button className="btn-something" style={ {width:50%} }>Decline</button>
```

What is the correct way for the `style=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value in style inline object must be a string:

```
style={{ width: "50%" }}>
```